# Mutable Variables in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, geojson

Pardon me if this is a completely idiotic question but I just can't figure it out.

#### Background Info

I'm writing an app in Node.js with the Express framework. I have a URI mapping designed to analyze some Twitter data for sentiment on a given subject in some aggregation units and return the GeoJSON object containing these results to the client.

Here are some details on the data.

- Aggregation units, States in the US, are stored as Points in a GeoJSON file, loaded via a `require` call. These points will later be used to make markers in a Leaflet map.
- Tweets are stored in a MongoDB database, accessed using the `mongodb` driver.

And this is the process for altering these GeoJSON Points

- Load the GeoJSON with `require`
- Query the MongoDB database for appropriate tweets
- Iterate over the features in the GeoJSON file

  - Iterate over the tweets in the result set

    - If the tweet is from within that feature

      - Analyze the sentiment within
      - Classify the feature using the sentiment
      - Set `marker.properties.class` to the classification
- Write the altered GeoJSON to the response

#### Problem

So here's my problem, the GeoJSON I load with `require` is never changed.

#### Question

Is data loaded via a call to `require` mutable? If not, is there a simple way to make it mutable, and by that I mean simpler than [copying the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)?

#### Bonus question

Does anyone know why `console.log()` doesn't work when a Node server is running with the Express framework? I swear it did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules can be deleted from cache. You just need to do:

`delete require.cache[moduleName];`

Anyway this is not the best approach.

It is much better to export a constructor function and instantiate a new object when needed. For example:

```
//in geo.js
function Geo() {...}
module.exports = Geo;

//in another module
var Geo = require('./geo.js');
var geo = new Geo();
```

Comment: I'll test this this afternoon